# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.String'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to populate value from Database to `Combobox` and when I run it I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.String'.'

`Status` is of type `tinyint`.

```
public void FillStatus()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Status FROM tblZaposleni_AD";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            using (SqlDataReader saReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (saReader.Read())
                {
                    string name = saReader.GetString(0);
                    ddlStatus.Items.Add(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your database column contains a byte. You're trying to read it as a string. Bytes can't be read as strings. Try reading it as a byte, using `GetByte`

Comment: What is the type of the column `Status` in the `tblZaposleni_AD` table in your db server?

Comment: And btw: the exception has a **stack trace** that pretty cleary tells you **where** you made the mistake.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) should be useful in deciding how to parse the value in .NET. It shows that `tinyint` is converted to `byte`.

Comment: It doesn't look like that try/catch actually does anything. You should just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SQL Server `tinyint` is converted to `byte` in .NET, you need to read it as such, then convert to a string:

```
byte dbValue = saReader.GetByte(0);
string name = dbValue.ToString();
ddlStatus.Items.Add(name);
```

Comment: What in case that I have integer `value` ?

Comment: @DobroSumljivMomak `byte`, as with `tinyint`, can store integral values between 0 and 255 only, whereas `int` can store integral values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

I find where the error comes from. Insted of

```
string name = saReader.GetString(0);
```

I just replace this line to this one

```
 string name = saReader.GetByte(0).ToString();
```